# About order of an index

Tags: notation

I have a simple question on precedence of operators, especially applying a function and an index.

Can we write $q(F)_i$ (without an additional pair of parentheses) for $(q(F))_i$?

Maybe, it would be better $q(F)(i)$?

What is the best way to denote this?

Comment: is there any other way to understand $q(F)_i$? I can't think of any, and my personal taste is as little parentheses as possible.

Comment: The first time you use this notation you may want to explicitly describe what you mean. Some readers may not find it obvious.

Comment: Is this something for which $q_i(F)$ is inappropriate? Unless there is a fear of misinterpreting for components or partials, that's my preference. Then $q(F)_i$.